# Dynamically loading typescript code using requirejs

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, requirejs

I have asp.net MVVM application (typescript + requirejs + knockout.js).

I have some c# models and I would like to have their reprezentation in typescript. I already done it.
I didn't used for that T4 but after opening application I'm making request to server and getting string with these typescript models.
I cannot use also existing tools because my C# models are very specific.

So response from server with my typescript models looks:

```
"class SomeModel {

    title: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>("");
}

class SomeModel2 {

    title: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>("");
}"
```

Problem is how to include this typescript code dynamically into my app using requirejs?

I would like to use it something like:

```
import SomeModel = require("../SomeModel")

class SomePage
{
    public model : SomeModel;
}
```

Comment: Are you implying that you are sending your typescript classes as strings through a json request? Your web server should be able to serve the typescript files itself without sending them to the browser as strings.

Comment: Ok so any suggestions how to autmatically serve typescipt files? I mean I would like to generate these typescript files automatically from C# classes after each C# class change.

Comment: I think typically you would just place the .ts files in a folder in your web project. require.js should then be able to request the files from the server with that path using "require(...)" like you have. Your ts files do probably need to have the "export" keyword to be accessible from other ts files like "export class SomePage". As for generating them T4 is certainly an option, but it sounds like you already have another solution for that.